# Why does my text fields gets cleared when I pressed a button that will reveal obscure text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a a sign-in page as side project, it contains two fields of text, Email address & Password, on the password field it has a button that will reveals the obscure text on click and re-obscure the password text on second click and so on.
Now the main problem is: Instead of revealing the password text on click, both text field gets cleared instead.

This is the code:

```
  bool _visiblePassword = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _visiblePassword = false;
  }

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();

  body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(28),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            TextFormField(
              controller: _emailController,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 213, 213)),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 197, 197, 197)),
                hintText: "Enter your email",
                fillColor: setupMainTheme,
              ),
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 18),

            TextFormField(
              controller: _passController,
              obscuringCharacter: '*',
              obscureText: !_visiblePassword,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 213, 213)),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    _visiblePassword ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () { 
                    setState(() {
                      _visiblePassword = !_visiblePassword;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 197, 197, 197)),
                hintText: "Enter your password",
                fillColor: setupMainTheme,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Can you show the full file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `_emailController` and `_passController` defined inside the `build` method, then move them outside it. This is so they don't get reinitialized when `setState` is called.

Answer (score 0):

first declare a password variable before the build state
String password = ''
then instead of using controller use

```
 onChanged: (value)=>setState(() {
                              this.password = value;
                            }),
```